# How do I find and remove Nginx from an EC2 instance?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I want to remove Nginx from my Amazon Linux EC2 server. How can I find it and remove/disable it?

Nginx is listening on port 80, and I need access to that port. It would be preferable to not have to stop the process every server reboot.

By the way, I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
 sudo rm -f -R /usr/local/nginx && rm -f /usr/local/sbin/nginx
```

Comment: How did you install it? If you used `apt-get` then you can use this 

`sudo apt-get purge nginx`. It will delete ALL config files and all other files.

Comment: @DisplayName I don't have `apt-get`, I have `yum` and nginx was installed on the EC2 by default.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's Amazon AMI Linux first you need to stop `nginx` service:

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

than you should disable it with:

```
sudo chkconfig nginx off
```

and if you like, uninstall it:

```
sudo yum remove nginx
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

If you used `apt-get` then you can use this:

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx
```

It will delete ALL files including config files.

Otherwise:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/nginx /etc/default/nginx /usr/sbin/nginx* /usr/local/nginx /var/run/nginx.pid /var/log/nginx
```

Should do it.

Comment: I don't have `apt-get`, I have `yum`. Nginx was installed on the EC2 by default.